# blob to text : Can not read file content when converting blob to text for pdf and doc files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am downloading a file and trying to read the file content as part of functionality in project. When I am reading .text file below code is working fine. But for .pdf it's not working.

**service.ts**

```
saveFile(response, filename) {

    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      console.log(fileReader.result);
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(blob);

    var result = filename.match('.pdf');
    if (result) {
      var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(blobURL);
    } else {
      saveAs(blob, filename);
    }
  }
```

I am able to save file with content however not able to read file text. File text looks like this[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing loads of option following is the code module I created to read pdf, doc and docx file. This module also provide file extension. In future I will make it fully functional library to read all types of documents, Just pass the file name it will return text.

https://github.com/bpandey3/fileparser/blob/master/utils/passfileReader.js

Dev dependencies

- node-stream-zip for doc and docx file
- pdfreader for reading pdf file system to read files

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cant view content of pdf by default so you need to add some third party lib to read it's content

Check this package [pdfreader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfreader)

Sample:

```
var PdfReader = require("pdfreader").PdfReader;
new PdfReader().parseFileItems("sample.pdf", function(err, item){
  if (item && item.text)
    console.log(item.text);
});
```

or

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("sample.pdf", (err, pdfBuffer) => {
  // pdfBuffer contains the file content
  new PdfReader().parseBuffer(pdfBuffer, function(err, item) {
    if (err) callback(err);
    else if (!item) callback();
    else if (item.text) console.log(item.text);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply however this code is when uploading file, my case is bit different as mentioned in question. I am downloading file and then want to read the blob and convert  it to text.